# Set email body content in google appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to send an email with a content related to my data such as in following piece of code I found on Datasource script of Google AppMaker Project Tracker template. But I don't understand how it works. How that **data.modifiedBy** reflect to the record in my datasource?

[image]

Any help from the floors? Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Notifications server side script in the template.

It has method `notifyAboutItemChanges_` which is passing the data to this record.

```
function notifyAboutItemChanges_(changes) {

  var settings = getAppSettingsRecord_()[0];

  if (!settings.EnableEmailNotifications) {
    return;
  }

  var data = {
    appUrl: settings.AppUrl,
    itemType: changes[0].Type,
    itemKey: changes[0]._key,
    itemName: changes[0].Name,
    modifiedBy: changes[0].ModifiedBy,
    changes: changes
  };

  // Email subject.
  var subjectTemplate =
          HtmlService.createTemplate(settings.NotificationEmailSubject);

}
```

This function is passing this data to your settings record.

So no magic here :) You need to pass the data to your record which will be replaced at run time with the values.

For more details on Email refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/email/) sample app.

Comment: wow really helpful got the brief idea on how to do it again thanks a lot bro!

Comment: Glad to help. See appmaker mail quotas as well once